# Can you learn piccolo by yourself?

Tags: flute, band, piccolo

I currently have played the flute for 4 years and I was wondering if I needed to have lessons and or a teacher to learn the piccolo. My parents said they won’t pay for lessons and I would have to buy a piccolo on my own. I am willing to pay for the piccolo itself but do not have the money for lessons. Is it possible?

Comment: We really don't know how well you already play the flute, what aptitudes you have, how good the piccolo will be that you buy yourself, or much else, for that matter. Somewhat like 'I'm going to buy a piece of string, I bought some before, how long will it be? And will it do the job?' Very difficult to come up with a helpful answer here. Sorry. But certainly worth having a good go on your own for a while!

Comment: It may be worth it to mention what type of piccolo you are looking to acquire. Is it metal, wood, or composite? Does it have a lip plate? Does it have a cylindrical or conical bore?

Answer (score 3):

Picking up the piccolo is honestly a pretty natural process for flutists - when I first started playing piccolo, I learned it on my own. After you get some familiarity with it, practice with a tuner, because the pitch tendencies of piccolo are different than flute.

Answer (score 2):

Learning piccolo by yourself is like learning any other instrument by yourself: you might have a natural talent and/or be lucky enough to avoid any pitfalls. Or you might end up doing something wrong and land in a dead-end that'll be very difficult to get out of.

Coming from the flute you have a head start, you know the fingerings, but there are important differences in embouchure, air-flow and tuning. You might pick them up naturally, but you might not.

In the end it comes down to the level you want to play at. If you want to play for fun you'll probably be okay. If you want to play in  a top-level orchestra you're going to need lessons.

Answer (score 2):

How are you learning flute?  If you HAVE a teacher, I'm sure a few minutes of each flute lesson could be a piccolo lesson!  Or if you're not taking regular lessons, but can afford to buy a piccolo, surely you can afford ONE lesson?   Or is there a piccolo player in your band you could hang out with?  (I guess someone who plays flute and wants to play piccolo IS in a band of some sort?)

Or just try.  As people are saying, it's not THAT different.

Comment: I do not take lessons. My friend is selling me her piccolo for 200 dollars. I have saved up this money for a long time so I can not in fact buy lessons. My friend gave up on piccolo and that’s why she is selling it to me so she can not help.